# Issues with calculating amino acid frequency

Tags: python

I am writing a program to determine the percentage of each amino acid in a given sequence. I was trying to make it useful for any sequence by making it output both the percentage of each amino acid and telling me which amino acids from a dictionary aren't present. I'm having some difficulties here and would really appreciate some guidance.

So more elaboration is i am trying to make it so the output shows the percentage of each amino acid in the provided string, including those that aren't in the string.

Here is my current code:

```
protein = """MKLFWLLFTIGFCWAQYSSNTQQGRTSIVHLFEWRWVDIALECERYLAPKGFGGVQVSPPNENVAIHNPFRPWWERYQPVSYKLCTRSGNEDEFRNMVTRCNNVGVRIYVDAVINHMCGNAVSAGTSSTCGSYFNPGSRDFPAVPYSGWDFNDGKCKTGSGDIENYNDATQVRDCRLSGLLDLALGKDYVRSKIAEYMNHLIDIGVAGFRIDASKHMWPGDIKAILDKLHNLNSNWFPEGSKPFIYQEVIDLGGEPIKSSDYFGNGRVTEFKYGAKLGTVIRKWNGEKMSYLKNWGEGWGFMPSDRALVFVDNHDNQRGHGAGGASILTFWDARLYKMAVGFMLAHPYGFTRVMSSYRWPRYFENGKDVNDWVGPPNDNGVTKEVTINPDTTCGNDWVCEHRWRQIRNMVNFRNVVDGQPFTNWYDNGSNQVAFGRGNRGFIVFNNDDWTFSLTLQTGLPAGTYCDVISGDKINGNCTGIKIYVSDDGKAHFSISNSAEDPFIAIHAESKL""" #exchange sequence for unique analysis
amino_acid = ['C', 'D', 'S', 'Q', 'K', 'P', 'T', 'F', 'A', 'X', 'G', 'I', 'E', 'L', 'H', 'R', 'W', 'M', 'N', 'Y', 'V']
for a in amino_acid:
    if a in protein:
        print "Percentage of" + amino_acid[a] + "is" + ((protein.count(a)) * 100 / len(protein))
    else:
        print amino_acid[a] + "is not in sequence"
```

This is what I did before which worked but wouldn't show the amino acids that don't appear at all (0%)

```
from collections import Counter
sequence = "MKLFWLLFTIGFCWAQYSSNTQQGRTSIVHLFEWRWVDIALECERYLAPKGFGGVQVSPPNENVAIHNPFRPWWERYQPVSYKLCTRSGNEDEFRNMVTRCNNVGVRIYVDAVINHMCGNAVSAGTSSTCGSYFNPGSRDFPAVPYSGWDFNDGKCKTGSGDIENYNDATQVRDCRLSGLLDLALGKDYVRSKIAEYMNHLIDIGVAGFRIDASKHMWPGDIKAILDKLHNLNSNWFPEGSKPFIYQEVIDLGGEPIKSSDYFGNGRVTEFKYGAKLGTVIRKWNGEKMSYLKNWGEGWGFMPSDRALVFVDNHDNQRGHGAGGASILTFWDARLYKMAVGFMLAHPYGFTRVMSSYRWPRYFENGKDVNDWVGPPNDNGVTKEVTINPDTTCGNDWVCEHRWRQIRNMVNFRNVVDGQPFTNWYDNGSNQVAFGRGNRGFIVFNNDDWTFSLTLQTGLPAGTYCDVISGDKINGNCTGIKIYVSDDGKAHFSISNSAEDPFIAIHAESKL" #exchange sequence for unique analysis
counts = Counter(sequence)
length = len(sequence)
dictionary = dict(counts)
amino_acids = list(dictionary)
freq = dictionary.values()
percentage = []
for item in freq:
    percentage.append(((item)/float(length))*100)
print "The percentage of each amino acid in the provided sequence are shown below:"
print str(zip(amino_acids, percentage))
```

Comment: Could you offer a more useful description of the problem than *"not working"*?

Comment: You must'n use `amino_acid[a]`, just use `a`. The `for` loop iterates over the values of the array, so `a` will be `'C'`, `'D'`, ...

Comment: yeah, "not working" isn't so grand... give us an example of the output, including any error messages, along with what you expected the output to be. (edit your question and add it there, don't just tell us in the comments)

Comment: You should check out [biopython](http://biopython.org/wiki/Main_Page), they have lots of great code for doing these types of analyses

Comment: I smell homework....

Answer (score 2):

It's worth going into some more detail on the problem you're trying to solve, but based on the gist you provided above I'm pretty certain what you're looking for is a `Counter` object.

Specifically:

```
>>> from collections import Counter:
>>> test = Counter("""MKLFWLLFTIGFCWAQYSSNTQQGRTSIVHLFEWRWVDIALECERYLAPKGFGGVQVSPPNENVAIHNPFRPWWERYQPVSYKLCTRSGNEDEFRNMVTRCNNVGVRIYVDAVINHMCGNAVSAGTSSTCGSYFNPGSRDFPAVPYSGWDFNDGKCKTGSGDIENYNDATQVRDCRLSGLLDLALGKDYVRSKIAEYMNHLIDIGVAGFRIDASKHMWPGDIKAILDKLHNLNSNWFPEGSKPFIYQEVIDLGGEPIKSSDYFGNGRVTEFKYGAKLGTVIRKWNGEKMSYLKNWGEGWGFMPSDRALVFVDNHDNQRGHGAGGASILTFWDARLYKMAVGFMLAHPYGFTRVMSSYRWPRYFENGKDVNDWVGPPNDNGVTKEVTINPDTTCGNDWVCEHRWRQIRNMVNFRNVVDGQPFTNWYDNGSNQVAFGRGNRGFIVFNNDDWTFSLTLQTGLPAGTYCDVISGDKINGNCTGIKIYVSDDGKAHFSISNSAEDPFIAIHAESKL""")
>>> test
Counter({'G': 52, 'N': 41, 'D': 35, 'V': 35, 'S': 33, 'F': 29, 'I': 28, 'R': 28, 'A': 27, 'L': 27, 'K': 24, 'T': 23, 'P': 22, 'Y': 21, 'E': 20, 'W': 19, 'C': 12, 'H': 12, 'Q': 12, 'M': 11})
```

which should be enough for you to go on. Let me know if you have any questions. Trying not to fully spoonfeed the answer though.

Comment: You could compare the `Counter`s keys with your `amino_acid` list (using `set`s, because order is irrelevant).

Answer (score 0):

```
protein = """MKLFWLLFTIGFCWAQYSSNTQQGRTSIVHLFEWRWVDIALECERYLAPKGFGGVQVSPPNENVAIHNPFRPWWERYQPVSYKLCTRSGNEDEFRNMVTRCNNVGVRIYVDAVINHMCGNAVSAGTSSTCGSYFNPGSRDFPAVPYSGWDFNDGKCKTGSGDIENYNDATQVRDCRLSGLLDLALGKDYVRSKIAEYMNHLIDIGVAGFRIDASKHMWPGDIKAILDKLHNLNSNWFPEGSKPFIYQEVIDLGGEPIKSSDYFGNGRVTEFKYGAKLGTVIRKWNGEKMSYLKNWGEGWGFMPSDRALVFVDNHDNQRGHGAGGASILTFWDARLYKMAVGFMLAHPYGFTRVMSSYRWPRYFENGKDVNDWVGPPNDNGVTKEVTINPDTTCGNDWVCEHRWRQIRNMVNFRNVVDGQPFTNWYDNGSNQVAFGRGNRGFIVFNNDDWTFSLTLQTGLPAGTYCDVISGDKINGNCTGIKIYVSDDGKAHFSISNSAEDPFIAIHAESKL""" #exchange sequence for unique analysis
amino_acid = ['C', 'D', 'S', 'Q', 'K', 'P', 'T', 'F', 'A', 'X', 'G', 'I', 'E', 'L', 'H', 'R', 'W', 'M', 'N', 'Y', 'V']
counts = {}
for amino in amino_acid: counts[amino] = 0
total = 0
for a in amino_acid:
    if a in protein:
        counts[a] = protein.count(a)
        fraction = float(counts[a]) / float(len(protein))
        percent = fraction * 100
        print "Percentage of " + a + " is:  %.2f%%" % percent
        total += percent
    else:
        print "Percentage of " + a + " is:  0.0%" 
print 'Total: ', str(total) + '%'
print 'Amino Acid Counts: ', counts
```